# "Save to drive" not working for files with a long url

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-api, google-drive-api, amazon-cognito

Added the google drive api to our code using the guides from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/savetodrive)

We need to save s3 files to google drive as an option. We use the code snippet below

Code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-savetodrive"
   data-src="//cloudfront_domain/path/to/s3_file.pdf?accessToken=cognitoToken"
   data-filename="SomeName.pdf"
   data-sitename="My Company Name">
</div>
```

The cloudfront points to a lambda which extracts the cognito token and performs custom ACL checks and then links to the file. We have an issue with the cognitoToken exceeding character limit for GET calls.
So google-drive API calls /savetodrivebutton internally as a POST call instead of GET and returns 405 (Method not allowed). This happens when the token is long.
Is there a way to solve this issue?